# docker containers endpoints names in the production environment

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I am developing a microservice application and using docker-compose for the orchestration.
I have an angular application and 2 microservices developed with spring boot.
In my localhost environment, I have successfully communicated between containers and send requests, but when I tried to run the docker-compose file in google shell instance, requests to the backend failed.

EndPoints in the angular project have this pattern

```
http://localhost:8090/**
```

I also tried to use container names defined in my docker-compose as

```
searchservice:8080/**
```

but it didn't work either.

This is my docker-compose configuration

```
version: '3.5'
services:



  searchservice:
    hostname: searchservice
    image: ayoubdali/searchservice:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: searchservice
    networks:
      - es-network
          #ipv4_address: 172.21.0.12
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch


  subscriber-service:
    hostname: subscriber-service
    image: ayoubdali/subscriberservice:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: subscriber-service
    networks:
      - es-network 
          #ipv4_address: 172.21.0.13
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2

  searchappfront:
    hostname: searchappfront
    image: frontservice:0.5.0
    container_name: searchappfront
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - subscriber-service
      - searchservice

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.6
    hostname: elasticsearch
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - es-network  
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo1
    networks:
      - es-network
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]

networks:
  es-network:
    attachable: true
```

Comment: what if you remove hostname instruction from services? Here is my working example compose - https://gitlab.com/gintsgints/vue-fullstack/-/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?  Can you reduce the `docker-compose.yml` file to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue (are the two MongoDB replicas and Kafka setup actually necessary, for example)?  What is the specific code producing the error?  Is it something that runs in a browser (a Vue or Angular or React application, for example)?

Comment: @DavidMaze when I use the hostname in the endPoint Url I got  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in my browser console . The problem is in the angular container, it can't reach the searchservice container nor the searchservice ( I reduced my docker-compose file configuration with only the front and the back-end services).

Comment: @GintsGints I got 404 not found when I remove the hostname from services. Thank you for the example but I can't see how it can help me,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the issue is that your Angular container (front) can't reach searchservice on port 8080 on a GCP instance while on your local environment it works

Since the error shown is related to DNS while using the hostname in the endPoint Url, make sure everything’s working correctly in terms of DNS and when you make a dns request to that hostname it resolves how it should. In addition, that there’s no any other GCP service or product such as Cloud DNS involved in this deployment